# Change an existing textarea to full_html

Tags: 7, forms, wysiwyg

I have [PET](http://drupal.org/project/pet) module enabled. As per my requirement, I have to change the mail body to a full_html one from normal textarea. It changes to ckeditor when I changed #type and #format. following is my code:

```
case 'pet_form':
  $form['mail_body']['#type'] = 'text_format';
  $form['mail_body']['#format'] = 'full_html';
break;
```

But when form submitted the mail body value turned to an array() instead of HTML based string.

Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: why dont you use rules to send pet email body?

Comment: The requirement is different, I have to give a HTML editor UI so that my client can handle editing those.

Comment: in pet there are functions like pet_send_mail and pet_send_one_mail

Comment: @Humanlove, Those functions are to invoke mail, What I need is to turn the PET mail content textarea editor (in admin) into a Drupal ckeditor(full_html).

I checked more, It seems to be a PET issue, as it doesn't handle submitted value properly when textarea format changes. I did a tweak with overwriting $form_state['values']['mail_body'].

Though, Its not the correct Drupal practice, It works. :)